# What is forcing the android service here to shut down?

Tags: android, service, abort

I have been facing this issue for quite sometime now. I have an application that connects via AIDL to an android remote service. Sometimes, I see that the service gets restarted with similar logs:-

```
04-11 23:52:35.225: E/dalvikvm-gc(21682): Could not mmap 3723264-byte ashmem region     'dalvik-mark-stack'
04-11 23:52:35.225: E/dalvikvm-heap(21682): dvmHeapBeginMarkStep failed; aborting
04-11 23:52:35.225: E/dalvikvm(21682): VM aborting
04-11 23:54:53.535: I/dalvikvm(21682): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
```

Can anyone give some insight here? 
Prima-facie, it appears that it may be some out-of-memory related issue?

Comment: Can you show your service..? or tell what resources it is using? like mediaplayer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. it is related to memory issue..**Ashmem is a shared memory mechanism that is able to discard some or all of its contents when memory pressure gets high**.. i think you are using many resources.. and not releasing them..

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you probably have a memory leak in your program.  You need to make sure that you release all resources after you are done with them, especially things like mediaplayers, web connections, etc.

Android will stop services it thinks aren't needed anymore on it's own.  In order to avoid the system shutting down your services or process you need to make sure that you don't cap out the memory on whatever device you have.  If you are running this in an AVM I would try modifying the settings so that the device has a bunch more memory.  If your program doesn't have a problem when the memory of the virtual device is increased you need to take a hard look at what resources you can release and when.